# MySQL Replication doesn't work from 1 computer but does from another

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I'm having a super odd error when using MySQL replication. In this setup I've got multiple servers, we got a Master Server, and then we got several slaves. The replication is working fine between Master and all the Slaves. However, there is one little exception to this rule. I've recently added a new Slave which we can call Slave A. When I make manual changes from my computer on the Master Server, it all replicates normally to all Slaves including Slave A. However when a colleague of mine tried making manual changes from their computer to the Master Server, it replicates out to all Slaves EXCEPT for Slave A.
There was a "very" small difference in our MySQL Server version, i'm running 5.7.17 while he was running 5.7.16 could that possibly affect it, feels like the version difference is so small it shouldn't matter?

So now I'm wondering what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you query the same command on both clients? Does he use a different user than you on your machine? If yes, could you try the same user on both clients? Usually, the last digit in the version are minor changes / bugfixes and might affect the behaviour but should not.

Comment: We use the exact same query, also the same user is being used when making the changes. Also changes made through our different applications work fine as well. It's just manual changes from any other computer than mine that seems to brake.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because the server is controlling the replication not the client. Are you also 100% sure the hostnames are the same?

Comment: Ye, that's my thought as well, Master Server is controlling the replication not client hence it shouldn't happen. Yes, hostname is the same for all the different slaves.

Comment: The clients must connect to the master to write and replicate, is the hostname, entered in the client, the same on your and your colleagues computer?

Comment: Yes, we all use the same "root" user to access the master and make changes with.